# Slideshow is getting stuck on final image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm currently trying to implement Javascript to slideshow through images like a carousel (developing for IE8 / IE9, otherwise CSS transitions / bootstrap would be the easier option)

The issue I have is that for the second group of images, it is getting stuck on the final image and not looping round like the first group.

There is also no way to set the interval differently, I tried adding separate ID's but got no luck, checking here to make sure the Javascript is correct.

JS

```
function slideSwitch() {
    var $active = $('#slideshow IMG.active');

    if ( $active.length == 0 ) $active = $('#slideshow IMG:last');

    var $next =  $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $('#slideshow IMG:first');

    $active.addClass('last-active');

    $next.css({opacity: 0.0})
        .addClass('active')
        .animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000, function() {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
}

$(function() {
    setInterval( "slideSwitch()", 5000 );
});
```

HTML

```
<a href="#">
    <div id="slideshow">
        <img src="images/chelsey.png" alt="" class="active"/>
        <img src="images/rob.png" alt="" />
        <img src="images/chris.png" alt="" />
        <img src="images/alex.png" alt="" />
    </div>
</a>

<a href="#">
    <div id="slideshow">
        <img src="images/ross.png" alt="" class="active"/>
        <img src="images/miryam.png" alt="" />
        <img src="images/jo.png" alt="" />
        <img src="images/katie.png" alt="" />
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
#slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:350px;
}

#slideshow IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
}

#slideshow IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
}

#slideshow IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same `id` for both slideshows, but `id`s have to be unique. You can just switch to classes. In addition, the function has to iterate over multiple slideshows, e.g. by using jQuery `each()`. Adjusted your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ar9ts2br/):

```js
function slideSwitch() {

    $(".slideshow").each(function () {
        var $active = $(this).find(".active");
        if ($active.length == 0) {
            $active = $(this).find("IMG:last");
        }
        var $next = $active.next().length ? $active.next() : $(this).find("IMG:first");

        $active.addClass('last-active');

        $next.css({
            opacity: 0.0
        })
            .addClass('active')
            .animate({
            opacity: 1.0
        }, 1000, function () {
            $active.removeClass('active last-active');
        });
    });
}

$(function () {
    setInterval("slideSwitch()", 5000);
});
```

```css
.slideshow {
    position:relative;
    height:350px;
}
.slideshow IMG {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:8;
}
.slideshow IMG.active {
    z-index:10;
}
.slideshow IMG.last-active {
    z-index:9;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#">
   <div class="slideshow">
       <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/" alt="" class="active"/>
        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/" alt="" />
   </div>
 </a>
 <a href="#">
   <div class="slideshow">
     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/" alt="" class="active"/>
     <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/2/" alt="" />
   </div>
 </a>
```